# CSV File in Scientific Notation when Downloading It

Tags: excel, csv

I've been trying to download a csv file from a web link. By doing so the numbers are downloaded in scientific notation and I cannot import them from Excel to make them appear as strings. What should I do?

This is the link:
https://www.sri.gob.ec/o/sri-portlet-biblioteca-alfresco-internet/descargar/673ce193-6cf8-46e4-82ee-c8a9fe927bfc/SRI_CATASTRO_AGENTES_RETENCION.csv

I've tried downloading from different web browsers with no result whatsoever.

Comment: You have to *import* the data into Excel, specifying that column's type as text. Note that *importing* the file is not the same as opening it.

Comment: If you open the file with Notepad ++ you will see, the numbers are saved as scientific notation.

Comment: The file could have been exported from Excel as csv, and the second column could have been phone numbers which excel tries to be "friendly about" so you don't have to worry about so many digits.  There are many good reasons to keep Excel away from your csv files and see that Excel is not a database.

Comment: What do you expect? The csv file itself has the RUC column numbers already in Scientific Notation. If you want them to appear as text strings, merely designate that column as text at the time you **IMPORT** the file using either Power Query or the Legacy Import Wizard. If the RUC numbers are supposed to be long strings of digits, then the problem is with how that file was generated, and you will need to contact the producer of the file.